# How to get star query optimization in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, query-optimization

I have a star schema but SQL Server 2005 always uses the clustered indexes to access a table. What parameters do I have to set to enable this optimization.

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlqueryprocessing/archive/2007/04/09/how-to-check-whether-the-final-query-plan-is-optimized-for-star-join.aspx and the DWH datasheet of SQL Server 2005 both claim, that SQL Server 2005 support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

What edition do you use? IIRC star query optimization is ONLY in the enterprise version of SQL Server 2005.